# How to increase speaker volume?

Tags: gnome, sound, multimedia

I have an ubuntu laptop, and can control the speaker volume with the built in keys.
However, the max volume is still pretty low in some applications.

Can I amplify the voice output further somehow?

Answer (score 5):

- First click here to open the sound menu:

  [image: Click me, I'm a button.]
- Then click sound preferences to open the sound preferences:

  [image: A menu, with buttons!]
- Now you can slide your volume above 100%

  [image: Sound preferences window]

Comment: I don't have the mixer icon anywhere (using a custom ubuntu build). How can I add it?

Comment: @ripper234: what is your "custom Ubuntu build"?

Comment: Google's build.

Comment: @ripper234: Google's build == ChromeOS? Or Google's Internal Ubuntu build?

Comment: internal build. I think I'll go ask on the internal forums.

Answer (score 0):

Open " Run an Application" in gnome desktop

Type sound in search box

click list of known application in below and select sound application in that you can adjust your sounds

[image: Open Sound in gnome desktop]